# Creating a new boost fusion sequence using another one

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, boost-fusion

Given a fusion sequence X, I would like to create a new fusion sequence Y whose implementation will be based on X. In particular, I would like to create a class template `make_fusion_conforming` so that

```
template <class X>
struct another_fusion_sequence : make_fusion_conforming <X> {};
```

will make `another_fusion_sequence<X>` fusion-conforming, so that I could call

```
auto sequence1 = another_fusion_sequence<X>(); //line 1
auto sequence2 = another_fusion_sequence<another_fusion_sequence<X>>(); // line 2
auto it1 = fusion::begin(sequence1);
auto it2 = fusion::begin(sequence2);
```

where `it1` and `it2` would be iterators to the first element of the sequences (which would in fact be the first element of the X sequence). Note that line 2 is also valid since `another_fusion_sequence<X>` is already fusion-conforming.

Using the boost extension documentation and the provided triple.cpp demo I came up with what is below. Apologies it is bit long but it is very simple as the implementation of `iterator` and `make_fusion_conforming` simply delegate to the already fusion-conforming sequence.

```
#include <boost/fusion/iterator/iterator_facade.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/iterator/value_of.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/iterator/deref.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/iterator/next.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/iterator/prior.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/iterator/distance.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/begin.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/end.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/size.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/category_of.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/sequence/sequence_facade.hpp>

namespace fusion = boost::fusion;

// Sequence is the sequence I want to make fusion-conforming
// BaseIter is a fusion-conforming iterator
// the implementation of iterator below is based entirely on BaseIter
template <class Sequence, class BaseIter>
struct iterator
: fusion::iterator_facade<iterator<Sequence, BaseIter>, typename fusion::traits::category_of<BaseIter>::type> {

    using base_iter_type = BaseIter;

    BaseIter m_base_iter;

    iterator(BaseIter base_iter)
    : m_base_iter(base_iter){}

    template <class It>
    struct value_of {

        using type = typename fusion::result_of::value_of<typename It::base_iter_type>::type;
    };

    template <class It>
    struct deref {

        using type = typename fusion::result_of::deref<typename It::base_iter_type>::type;

        static type call(const It& iter) {
            return fusion::deref(iter.m_base_iter);
        }
    };

    template <class It>
    struct next {

        using type = typename fusion::result_of::next<typename It::base_iter_type>::type;

        static type call(const It& iter) {
            return fusion::next(iter.m_base_iter);
        }
    };

    template <class It>
    struct prior {

        using type = typename fusion::result_of::prior<typename It::base_iter_type>::type;

        static type call(const It& iter) {
            return fusion::prior(iter.m_base_iter);
        }
    };

    template <class It1, class It2>
    struct distance {

        using type = typename fusion::result_of::distance<typename It1::base_iter_type, typename It2::base_iter_type>::type;

        static type call(const It1& iter1, const It2& iter2) {
            return fusion::distance(iter1.m_base_iter, iter2.m_base_iter);
        }
    };

};

// Base is the fusion-conforming sequence
// Sequence is the sequence I want to make fusion-conforming
// once again, implementation is based entirely on the Base sequence
template <class Base, class Sequence>
struct make_fusion_conforming
: public Base
, public fusion::sequence_facade<Sequence, typename fusion::traits::category_of<Base>::type> {

    using Base::Base;

    template <class Seq>
    struct begin {

        using type = iterator<Seq, typename fusion::result_of::begin<Base>::type>;

        static type call(Seq& seq) {
            return type(fusion::begin(static_cast<Base&>(seq)));
        }
    };

    template <class Seq>
    struct end {

        using type = iterator<Seq, typename fusion::result_of::end<Base>::type>;

        static type call(Seq& seq) {
            return type(fusion::end(static_cast<Base&>(seq)));
        }
    };

    template <class Seq>
    struct size {
        using type = typename fusion::result_of::size<Base>::type;

        static type call(Seq& seq) {
            return fusion::size(static_cast<Base&>(seq));
        }
    };

    template <class Seq>
    struct empty {

        using type = typename fusion::result_of::empty<Base>::type;

        static type call(Seq& seq) {
            return fusion::empty(static_cast<Base&>(seq));
        }
    };

    template <class Seq, class N>
    struct at {

        using type = typename fusion::result_of::at<Base, N>::type;

        static type call(Seq& seq) {
            return fusion::at<N>(static_cast<Base&>(seq));
        }
    };

    template <class Seq, class N>
    struct value_at {

        using type = typename fusion::result_of::value_at<Base, N>::type;
    };
};
```

Unfortunately, trying to take the begin iterator fails...

```
#include <boost/fusion/include/vector.hpp>

template <class... T>
struct sequence1
: make_fusion_conforming< fusion::vector<T...>, sequence1<T...> > {

};

using seq1 = sequence1<int, float, double>;

// the below fails with:
// No type named 'type' in 'boost::fusion::result_of::begin<sequence1<int, float, double> >'
using test1 = fusion::result_of::begin<seq1>::type;

int main() {}
```

Can someone help me with this? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that Boost.Fusion's extension machinery does not recognize that `make_fusion_conforming` is a "sequence façade". The first thing fusion does when working with intrinsic operations (begin, end, value_at, etc...) is check the tag of the sequence in question. It first checks if your type has a `fusion_tag` associated type (and takes it as its tag), then checks if it's a MPL sequence and if the checks fail it determines that the sequence has a `non_fusion_tag` tag. In order for all your boilerplate to work the tag of `sequence1` needs to be `sequence_facade_tag`, and you get that by deriving from `sequence_facade` but by also deriving from `Base` (`fusion::vector` in this case that has a tag of `vector_tag`) you have made `fusion_tag` ambiguous and accordingly `tag_of<seq1>::type` turns to be `non_fusion_tag`. A possible solution could be adding a `using fusion_tag = fusion::sequence_facade_tag;` to `make_fusion_conforming` resolving the ambiguity (another could be specializing `boost::fusion::traits::tag_of<sequence1<T...>>::type`).

[Running on WandBox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/937API7g82ZBKfog).